# locate source of local php settings

Tags: php

When I pull up phpinfo() from my webroot it details local and master php config settings. I'm familiar with the principal -- master settings are handled in the main php.ini file and can be overridden in site directories with php.ini files, ini_set() calls, or .htaccess files (depending on how the server is configured).

For a few settings I'm seeing local values that differ from the master settings, and for the life of me, can't locate where they are coming from. The loaded/parsed php.ini section of phpinfo() doesn't shed any light, and I've grep'd the heck out of the server trying to find where specific settings are found in files, without success.

Is there any way to locate the source of a setting?

Comment: check web server configs and .htaccess files.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already checked "loaded ini files" section, there are a few more places where the settings can be defined:

- if you're running Apache module, check for php_value in its config files
- check for php_value in .htaccess
- if you're using fastcgi (with nginx, apache or anything else), extra parameters can be specified in the command line (although who would do this?)
- there are also default PHP setting
- ini_set directive in the code above or in auto-prepended file defined in auto_prepend_file directive
- this page http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php also mentions something about Windows registry and .user.ini (oh gosh, never thought about this!)

Answer (score 0):

Also consider ini_get_all

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php

As it tells you the global and local values, so you can see if an option is being overridden